# Is there a name for a hashtable with a tree for each bin instead of a list?

Tags: ds.data-structures, terminology

It is well-known that the worst case performance for a [chaining hashtable](http://infoweekly.blogspot.nl/2010/01/basic-hashtables.html), is O(n), where n is the number of objects in the table. The normal assumption is that the hash is either uniform, or secure, however this is [not always the case](http://armoredbarista.blogspot.de/2012/02/investigating-hashdos-issue.html).

One possible solution to this problem would be to use a tree, or other O($\log n$) data structure, instead of the list. This would result in the worst-case performance of O($\log n$) for insertion and retrieval, at the expense of adding an extra constraint on the import data, namely that it would need to be comparable.

Is there a name for such a data structure?

Comment: The brouhaha around that "HashDOS attack" baffled me: It's essentially the standard motivation given for universal hashing, in undergrad algorithm classes. Why were people acting so surprised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a name for it: Hashtable.

You can have whatever you want for collision bins: Lists, trees, hashtables, whatever you fancy.

Answer (score 2):

You call them “the structure from Knuth 6.4 exercise 38”.  This is a bit unfair because it does not give credit to P. F. Windley who has suggested this structure first, but then anyone can look up that information in Knuth easily.

Comment: This isn't really an answer but a comment. Would probably be better in the future to use the comments section for commentary, since you have enough rep for comments.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at Judy arrays:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array

http://judy.sourceforge.net/